# PHP Fatal error when using maia mail guard with CentOS 6.6

Tags: php, mysql, apache, php-5.3, centos6

I installed maia mail guard with Smarty templates on CentOS 6.6 x64. when I open GUI on browser it will give below error on console... I searched everywhere for a solution but I couldn't...

Guys, If you have solution it will be most help for me. Thank you.

```
mydomain.com/maia/stats.php (This is the browser URL for bellow error)

# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8192 in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/error.php on line 135, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php
maia: 2015-01-01 16:57:55 (IST) -  - Function session_is_registered() is deprecated at /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/authcheck.php line [83]\n, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8192 in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/error.php on line 135, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php
maia: 2015-01-01 16:57:55 (IST) -  - Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated at /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/smarty.php line [172]\n, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "themes/ocean_surf/templates/stats.tpl"  on line 59 "{$lang.text_efficiency}  {$eff_pct*100|string_format:"%.2f"}%" unknown modifier "string_format" <-- \n  thrown in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/libs/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 59, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php



mydomain.com/maia/settings.php (This is the browser URL for bellow error)


PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8192 in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/error.php on line 135, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php

maia: 2015-01-01 17:28:26 (IST) -  - Function session_is_registered() is deprecated at /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/authcheck.php line [83]\n, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8192 in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/error.php on line 135, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8192 in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/smarty.php on line 172, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php

maia: 2015-01-01 17:28:26 (IST) - Warning - filemtime(): stat failed for themes/ocean_surf/compiled/59e5e722117fd6f48e4334ed2476e4e289b7cecb.file.settings.tpl.php at /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/libs/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_resource.php line [772]\n, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "themes/ocean_surf/templates/settings.tpl"  on line 306 "<input type=text size=7 name=level1 value="{$level1|string_format:"%1.3f"}">" unknown modifier "string_format" <-- \n  thrown in /var/www/html/mailguard/maia/libs/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 306, referer: mydomain.com/maia/welcome.php
```

Comment: Smarty don't know `string_format` modifier used in `themes/ocean_surf/templates/stats.tpl` on line 59.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't change the code. All are default settings. I downloaded this tar.gz file twice from the source. But it will give same error.

Comment: You found everywhere for a solution? You search for a solution when you haven't found one, you find a solution if you have found one.

Comment: Sorry, I correct it. I couldn't find any... Some guys says it is something with user:group permission. I tried. But not work..

Comment: Looks like poorly written code. It also uses deprecated functions, which probably means that it is rather old (their [website](http://www.maiamailguard.com/maia/wiki) was last updated in 2011, so probably true). I would try to find a more up-to-date, and maintained, project that does what you need.

Comment: My main task is set up a mail server. So I can manage it via maia mail guard. I used CentOS 6.5 (x64), Postfix, My-sql, Dovecot, Spam Assassin, ClamAV,  Amavisd-new, Postfix Admin and Maia Mail Guard. All other parts are well configured. But when I installed maia. It gave those errors, notice and warnings. If you have well prepared doc about maia mial guard, it will be great help for me.